# Starting/Stopping services in a host as part of K8S pod deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

We run K8S clusters based on custom VM images that have corporate standard services and utilities. How can a pod/container have access to those? For example, how to start a service in the host as part of deploy/undeploy

Comment: What distro? Assuming it's systemd and `systemctl` you need?

Answer (score 4):

You can mount the systemd sockets into the Pod's container. From there you either need [polkit](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/polkit/) permissions to run the commands as a non privileged user, or you need to run the container privileged. The Pod spec to do so is as follows:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: dbus-pod
  labels:
    app: dbus
spec:
  containers:
  - name: dbus-container
    image: centos:7
    command: ['systemctl','status','sshd']
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
    - name: run-dbus
      mountPath: /var/run/dbus
    - name: run-systemd
      mountPath: /run/systemd
    - name: bin-systemctl
      mountPath: /usr/bin/systemctl
      readOnly: true
    - name: etc-systemd
      mountPath: /etc/systemd/system
      readOnly: true
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
  - name: run-dbus
    hostPath:
      path: /var/run/dbus
  - name: run-systemd
    hostPath:
      path: /run/systemd
  - name: bin-systemctl
    hostPath:
      path: /usr/bin/systemctl
  - name: etc-systemd
    hostPath:
      path: /etc/systemd/system
```

Then you have to figure out how you want to schedule the Pod on your cluster. If you wanted to run something on every node once, you could create a [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) and remove it.  A [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) might be more appropriate if you have selectors to define where you want the Pod to run.

There are also projects like [go-systemd](https://github.com/coreos/go-systemd) that control dbus via the `/var/run/dbus` socket and take the place of all the systemd/systemctl setup.

Comment: Does this still work? I'm trying this and it doesn't work. Can't even ask the question on stackoverflow, it's immediately closed.